# Render Rmarkdown to directory outside R package

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a R package that generates a RMarkdown html report. The .Rmd file lives in the system library/package directory.
I would like to create a function `htmlreport()` to save the html report to the specified output directory path.
In case `output_path` is not specified the function should give the possibility to browse to the output folder.

After rendering I would also like to open the resulting html report.

I am no sure how to do this. It seems that the path to the output file is always relative to the .Rmd file.  How can I achieve this?

```
htmlreport <- function(output_path = NULL){
 f <- system.file("inst/rmd", "html_report.Rmd", package = "abc")

 if (is.null(outputh_path)) { 
    output_path <- ?? "Choose output folder" ....??
 }

 rmarkdown::render(f, output_dir = output_path) 

 # and open the html report..?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output_dir` can be any path, not only relative to rmd file.

To select a folder, you can use function `choose.dir()` in base R package `utils` or function `selectDirectory()` in `rstudioapi` (which means that it will only work if function is launched from `rstudio`)

To display the html file use function `browseURL` from base R package `utils` using url constructed with `paste0("file://",<full path of your file using / separator>)`